# Showing contrary results on the same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to perform a single query that do the work of two queries I already have. Let me explain a little bit.

**Query 1**

```
select count(*) as equal, someField from table where field1 = field2 group by someField;
```

**Result of Query 1**

```
-----------------
|equal|someField|
-----------------
| 90  | some1   |
| 45  | some2   |
-----------------
```

**Query 2**

```
select count(*) as different, someField from table where field1 != field2 group by someField;
```

Note the `!=`, that's the only difference from the `Query 1` (and the alias from the count off course).

**Result of Query 2**

```
---------------------
|different|someField|
---------------------
| 10      | some1   |
| 55      | some2   |
---------------------
```

So I end up with two results but would be nice to have the same data on a single query.

**Expected Result**

```
---------------------------
|equal|different|someField|
---------------------------
| 90  | 10      | some1   |
| 45  | 55      | some2   |
---------------------------
```

I would normally try many things until I find the expected result but here I have no idea how to begin.

**EDIT**

I'd try @Rahul answer and got this result:

```
select 
count(case when field1 = field2 then 1 else 0 end) as equal, 
count(case when field1 != field2 then 1 else 0 end) as different,
someField 
from table 
group by someField;

---------------------------
|equal|different|someField|
---------------------------
| 100 | 100     | some1   |
| 100 | 100     | some2   |
---------------------------
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `CASE` statement to achieve the same, like below

```
select 
sum(case when field1 = field2 then 1 else 0 end) as equal, 
sum(case when field1 != field2 then 1 else 0 end) as different,
someField 
from table 
group by someField;
```

Comment: It gives me the same number for `equal` and `different` and that number is the total of every `someField`.

Comment: @Gepser, try the edited query and see if it does correctly.